# Session state in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In regular MVC, I'm used to be able to do the following:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(){
    Session["User"] = new User();

    return View();
}
```

Giving me this option in the view:

```
<div>
    @if(Session["User"] != null){
        <p>Welcome @Session["User"].Username</p>
    }
</div>
```

In ASP.NET Core, Session state isn't implemented because of the various OS' capable of running this application. I've seen that I can use `IMemoryCache` and `IDistributedCache` instead, but I'm not quite sure how, given this scenario.

Any simple and well explained methods for doing this?

Comment: session is available, but you have to opt into it, it is not enabled by default https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html#a-working-sample-using-session

Comment: This looks promising. Funny I haven't come across this yet. Will have a look at this later and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @JoeAudette Okay, this works pretty well, but still I cannot get the Session from within my view, or can I?

Comment: Best way to manage session in asp.net core is posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192568/asp-net-core-session-state/59487707#59487707

Answer (score 1):

Session state in ASP.NET Core is possible. I fixed it by follow these steps:

**Add the following package to your project.json**:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session`

**Configure the session service**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options => 
            // Add any options you want here
            // EXAMPLE
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        );
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

**All done**
Now you should be able to do the following in your controller

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        TempData["SomeProperty"] = "Some data";
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div>
    <p>@TempData["SomeProperty"]</p>
</div>
```

Further reading material from [learn.microsoft.com documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state)