# ASP.NET Core Session State

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller where I have several methods. In the login method, I start a `HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("ID")`, if the login is successful. This ID is the id of the User logged in. I am using this ID in many other methods to do more calculations and queries. In every method, I have to declare a variable like
`?int userId = HttpContext.Session.GetINT32("ID")` to use this variable in that method.

How can I declare it globally in a way where I can use it in other Action methods without using the `HttpContext.Session.GetInt32` statement. I am just trying to use the DRY principle, so that my code is cleaner.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    private readonly IRepository _repo;

    public HomeController(DataContext context, IRepository repo)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._repo = repo;
    }

    public int GetUserId()
    {
       return (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("ID");
    }
```

Comment: I am using MVC, can I just put the GetUserId() method in the Home Controller. I don't really have APIBaseController.

Comment: Since you use MVC then it's obvious you can have a base controller.
The base controller is a class that you implement and not provided by the base class lib.
Provide your HomeController implementation probably I may be able to help you out with what I have proposed.

Comment: @FaizanRahman, Just a suggestion
e.g.
`public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{
  private readonly DataContext _context;
  private readonly IRepository _repo;

    public HomeController(DataContext context, IRepository repo)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._repo = repo;
    }

    public int GetUserId()
    {
       return (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("ID");
    }
}
public class HomeController : BaseController { // pass the required contructor params, I coldn't show them due to character limit}

`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), then you can get the user Id like this:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId(); // <-- this is inside controller
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to manage Session (globally) in ASP.NET Core is :

#### 1). Add  Static Class SessionExtensions.cs

```
       public static class SessionExtensions
        {
            public static void SetObject(this ISession session, string key, object value)
            {
                session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
            }

            public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
            {
                var value = session.GetString(key);
                return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
            }

            public static void SetBoolean(this ISession session, string key, bool value)
            {
                session.Set(key, BitConverter.GetBytes(value));
            }

            public static bool? GetBoolean(this ISession session, string key)
            {
                var data = session.Get(key);
                if (data == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return BitConverter.ToBoolean(data, 0);
            }

            public static void SetDouble(this ISession session, string key, double value)
            {
                session.Set(key, BitConverter.GetBytes(value));
            }

            public static double? GetDouble(this ISession session, string key)
            {
                var data = session.Get(key);
                if (data == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return BitConverter.ToDouble(data, 0);
            }
        }
```

#### 2). Add Static class UserSession.cs

```
    public static class UserSession
        {
            private static IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
            public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            {
                _accessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }

            public static HttpContext HttpContext => _accessor.HttpContext;


            public static Guid UserId
            {
                get
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId") == null || Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId")) == Guid.Empty)
                        return Guid.Empty;
                    else
                        return Guid.Parse(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId")));
                }
                set
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", Convert.ToString(value));
                }
            }


            public static byte[] ProfileImage
            {
                get
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Session.GetObject<byte[]>("ProfileImage") == null)
                        return null;
                    else
                        return HttpContext.Session.GetObject<byte[]>("ProfileImage");
                }
                set
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetObject("ProfileImage", value);
                }
            }

            public static string JwtToken
            {
                get
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwtToken") == null)
                        return null;
                    else
                        return HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwtToken");
                }
                set
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("JwtToken", value);
                }
            }

            public static string FirstName
            {
                get
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("FirstName") == null)
                        return null;
                    else
                        return HttpContext.Session.GetString("FirstName");
                }
                set
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("FirstName", value);
                }
            }

            public static string LastName
            {
                get
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("LastName") == null)
                        return null;
                    else
                        return HttpContext.Session.GetString("LastName");
                }
                set
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("LastName", value);
                }
            }

            public static string FullName { get { return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName) ? FirstName : string.Empty) + " " + (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName) ? LastName : string.Empty); } }


            public static string Email
            {
                get
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email") == null)
                        return null;
                    else
                        return HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email");
                }
                set
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Email", value);
                }
            }
        }
```

#### 3).Add this in startup.cs

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     services.AddSession(options =>
                {
                    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);//You can set Time   
                });

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSession();

        UserSession.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
    }
```

#### 4). Voila. Done

```
--------------------
How to use :

Set session (Ex:Set session for UserId) > UserSession.UserId = 1;
Get session (int id = UserSession.UserId)
```

Comment: PERFECT SOLUTION . Superb @kgajjar20